# How to show a loading animation or a div while my bean prepares a download in the managed bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've used primefaces commandlink with ajax but then the download window simply doesnt appear, if I turn ajax off (`ajax="false"`) then the download window shows up but my transparent div which I use as loading screen doesnt. What other ways is there to show the user i'm processing his download?

Comment: Could you include some of your current code so we can see what you're trying right now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [commandLink fileDownload and ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254887/commandlink-filedownload-and-ajax)