# Show status on start of pe:exporter and hide status when it is finished

Tags: primefaces

Very similar to [Show status on start of p:fileDownload and hide status when it is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254887/show-status-on-start-of-pfiledownload-and-hide-status-when-it-is-finished)

but in this case I have a datatable that is taking a long time to export, so I need that the pe:exporter show a spinner or a status when the user clicks on the export button and hide it when the export file is send back to the client.

Currently my export button looks like:

```html
<h:commandLink style="float:right;padding:3px;margin-top:2px;" immediate="true" 
  styleClass="fa fa-file-pdf-o" title="Export to PDF">
  <pe:exporter type="pdf" encoding="iso-8859-1" target="datatable"
    fileName="ExportResult"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I have Primefaces 6.0

Comment: did you try to work with the Ajax Status ?!?

Comment: There is no ajax involved here... The exporter makes a standard POST http request

Comment: if i understand your question you are searching something to make like a loading status is that what you are looking for ?!?

Comment: Yes. When the user clicks on the export a loading status must show and when the export file is sent back to the client it must hide it. p:fileDownload  does just that, but I have an exporter instead

Comment: did you try the ajaxStatus of the primefaces site if yes tell me if non http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact we use it across our entire application but as I have said its of no use here as there is no ajax involved

Comment: i see that you use a commandLink why not using his ajax event ?!?

Comment: Something new ???

Comment: I think I have found a solution, and and easy one indeed. I will post it later. Thanks @Yagami Light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found a solution.

```html
<h:commandLink style="float:right;padding:3px;margin-top:2px;" immediate="true"           styleClass="fa fa-file-pdf-o" title="Export to PDF"
  onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startHandler, endHandler)">
  <pe:exporter type="pdf" encoding="iso-8859-1" target="dataTable"
    fileName="resultadoConsulta"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Please  note the `onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startHandler, endHandler)"` part.

This was the first part of the solution. startHandler and endHandler are javascript functions that shows and hides a spinner, like the ones in the p:fileDownload showcase.

The second part was the tricky one. I have a custom exporter and was missing this line on the response:

```
externalContext.addResponseCookie(Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, "true", Collections.<String, Object> emptyMap());
```

This line of code sets a flag that the monitorDownload function of Primefaces was expecting.

After that, all is working!